# APC Smart-UPS X 1500VA Warning State: Connect Battery

Tags: battery, ups

I have an APC Smart-UPS X 1500V which I just connected to a power source. When I turned the device on it was beeping and giving a flashy red light at the most right icon of the control panel.

[image]

The error message "Warning State: Connect Battery" was displaying on the screen of the control panel.

I tried resetting the device to factory defaults.

What is causing this and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You say you just connected it to a power source. Did you also just purchase it? Most UPSes ship with a cable disconnected from the battery that you need to reconnect before plugging it in.

Comment: @ChrisPowell No, I didn't just buy it, we had it in use for the company and it got replaced, now when i'm trying to start it back up, i get this error. The battery in this device is placed in 2012. The cable for the battery is well plugged in.

Comment: Just looked at the manual for that UPS. APC describes it as the "Replace Battery" indicator. Is it possible your battery has gone bad?

Comment: @ChrisPowell I have no knowlegde of that. I've only been around here since 2015. The UPS is probably there for a couple of years already. Is replacing the battery the only solution when it went "bad"?

Comment: Yep. If the battery is bad, then you'll need to order a new one. I would call APC or poke around on their website and see if they can help you out.

Comment: @ChrisPowell Alright, but is this the only thing that can cause this message? (Just making sure that when i ordered a battery, the same message isn't displaying)

Comment: Either the manual or APC support should be able to tell you that.

Comment: @ChrisPowell Not to sound like a newb, but when ordering a battery, the problem is mostly gone?

Comment: If the battery is, indeed, bad and you order a new one and connect it correctly, then the UPS should work fine until that new battery goes bad.

Comment: @ChrisPowell Alright, but what could be bad more instead of the battery causing this problem?

Comment: If anything else besides the battery is bad then it would be easier to buy a new UPS.

Comment: @ChrisPowell It doesnt look bad.. haven't noticed any damage or anything.

Comment: From the manual:  
The replace battery LED is illuminated  
The battery has a weak charge.   
Allow the battery to recharge for at least four hours. Then, perform a self-test.  
If the problem persists after recharging, replace the battery.
The replacement battery is not properly
connected.
Ensure that the battery connector is securely connected.

Comment: Lead-acid batteries usually have a ~5 - 7 year lifetime when **well maintained**, but left unplugged, the battery likely completely discharged and can no longer hold a full charge. Even if the supply runs after charging it for a while, **test it** under load.

Comment: I have this happen on a brand new unit

Comment: The replacement battery is RBC115.